# How to fix requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 while installing grunt plugins?

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-plugins

I am trying to install some Grunt plugins like `grunt-contrib-clean` and `grunt-contrib-watch`
using `npm install grunt-contrib-clean --save-dev`
and `npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev`

I got these warnings:

> npm WARN stellarhse@1.0.0 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.10.0 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

How can I fix them?

Thank you.

Comment: install grunt 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 - the warning is telling you you need grunt for the other package to work but it isn't installed

Answer (score 0):

mostly you didn't installed grunt locally

try to install grunt locally by run this command

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Comment: This did not resolve my issue but I saw that this "mostly" worked in another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315196/requires-a-peer-of-grunt-0-4-0

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem,

- First, Ensured that the peer dependencies section in the package.json file is empty
- Second, I updated npm using

> npm update

- Third, install grunt cli globally using

> npm install -g grunt-cli.

- Finally switched to the path where the project in and complete installing grunt itself and the plugins I need and worked well.

> npm install grunt --save-dev
>
> npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
>
> npm install grunt-contrib-clean --save-dev

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone with a similar problem I just received this error on a successful Grunt 1.0.4 install:

```
grunt-contrib-concat@0.1.3 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none is installed
```

and none of the above answers worked, ie:

```
npm update
npm install grunt-contrib-concat --save-dev
```

did not resolve the problem / get the latest version

The only fix was to find THE LATEST VERSION of grunt-contrib-concat on git and overwrite explicitly:

```
grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1 --save-dev
```